# C# Overwrite text file - nothing is written to file

Tags: c#, streamwriter, system.io.file

I have two methods: `saveFile` and `saveAsToFile`. The first one is supposed to overwrite the contents of the current, existing file. While the second is supposed to save as a new file (if the current is non-existing or the user just wants to make a copy.)

When I use the `saveAsToFile` method it works every time. When I use the `saveFile` method it doesn't write anything. (I DO see the "Saved!" MessageBox, though.)

Here are my methods:

```
    public void saveFile(string[] inData, string inDataTitle) 
    {
        //This method saves the file
        SaveFileDialog savefile;
        string trueFileName;

        if (isStrArrayNotEmpty(inData)) {
            //Only attempt to save the file if there is anything written in the textArea

            if (f.getDocumentSavedStatus()) {
                if (f.getDocumentChangedStatus()) {
                    savefile = new SaveFileDialog();

                    if (inDataTitle.EndsWith("*")) {
                        //Remove the asterisk from the document name

                        savefile.FileName = inDataTitle.Substring(0, inDataTitle.Length - 1);
                    }
                    else {
                        savefile.FileName = inDataTitle;
                    }

                    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(savefile.FileName, false);
                    foreach (string line in inData) {
                        sw.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                    sw.Flush();
                    if (sw.BaseStream != null)
                        sw.BaseStream.Flush();
                    sw.Close();

                    /*
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(savefile.FileName, false))
                        foreach (string line in inData) {
                            sw.WriteLine(line);
                        }
                    */

                    f.setDocumentName(string.Empty);
                    trueFileName = Path.GetFileName(savefile.FileName);
                    f.setDocumentName(trueFileName);
                    f.setDocumentSavedStatus(true);
                    f.setDocumentChangedStatus(false);      //Changes saved, status updated

                    MessageBox.Show("Saved!");
                }
            }
            else {
                //If the document hasn't been saved before, send the values to the 'Save As' method

                saveAsToFile(inData, inDataTitle);
            }
        }
    }

    public void saveAsToFile(string[] inData, string inDataTitle) 
    {
        //This method checks if there is anything written in the texArea,
        //if so it prompts the user to save the file to disk (Save As)

        SaveFileDialog savefile;
        string trueFileName;

        if (isStrArrayNotEmpty(inData)) {
            //Only attempt to save the file if there is anything written in the textArea

            savefile = new SaveFileDialog();

            if (inDataTitle.EndsWith("*")) {
                //Remove the asterisk from the document name

                savefile.FileName = inDataTitle.Substring(0, inDataTitle.Length - 1);
            }
            else {
                savefile.FileName = inDataTitle;
            }

            savefile.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";

            if (savefile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(savefile.FileName, false);
                foreach (string line in inData) {
                    sw.WriteLine(line);
                }
                sw.Flush();
                if (sw.BaseStream != null)
                    sw.BaseStream.Flush();
                sw.Close();


                /*
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(savefile.FileName))
                    foreach (string line in inData) {
                        sw.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                */

                f.setDocumentName(string.Empty);
                trueFileName = Path.GetFileName(savefile.FileName);
                f.setDocumentName(trueFileName);
                f.setDocumentSavedStatus(true);
                f.setDocumentChangedStatus(false);      //Changes saved, status updated
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see by the comments in the code; I tried using `using`, and then I tried to "manually flush" the `streamwriter`, but nothing works.

Using `saveAsToFile` works every time. It overwrites the text file as expected, no problems. While `saveFile` doesn't write anything to the file. (Leaving it unchanged.)

I tried looking for errors in `saveFile` by using `MessageBox.Show` to print the values of `savefile.Filename` and `line` in the appropriate places - they all worked as expected, yet nothing is written to the actual text file.

`isStrArrayNotEmpty` returns true if the string array does not contain any white spaces.
`getDocumentSavedStatus` returns the value of a `boolean` which tells if the file has been saved before or not (existent / non-existent)
`getDocumentChangedStatus` returns the value of a `boolean` which tells if the file has been modified or not (asterisk by the end of the file name, indicating that work will be lost if the user shuts down the application.)

Comment: I would recommend using Visual Studio debugger. And spending some time analyzing your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the inDataTitle parameter include the path of the filename you're trying to save? If not, it's likely saving to a file of the same name but in a different folder.

After your line:-

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(savefile.FileName, false);
```

add the line:-

```
MessageBox.Show(((FileStream)(sw.BaseStream)).Name);
```

and it'll tell you where the file is being saved.

Comment: You're right. The path was missing! I will attempt to re-write my code now (I'm currently trying to merge the two methods into one.) Thank you. =)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(savefile.FileName, false);
   foreach (string line in inData) {
        sw.WriteLine(line);
    }
    sw.Flush();
    if (sw.BaseStream != null)
        sw.BaseStream.Flush();
    sw.Close();
```

with

```
File.WriteAllLines(saveFile.Filename, inData);
```

Comment: I tried, but sadly it didn't work. Same result as before. (Using the line you suggested in the method 'saveAsToFile' does work, but not in the method 'saveFile'.)

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger? Do you know if savefile.Filename really has the value you expect?

Comment: I don't really know how the bugger works. I use MessageBox.Show to print the values of the variables, when running the application.
EDIT: Yes, the file name is what I expect it to be.